# Get Folder Path

Tags: c#, path

I want to get the path of the folder to a textbox and the name of the folder is **Images12345**. I tried this.

```
//Inside the folder "Images12345"
string[] pics = { "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg" };
int i = 0;
```

Then in my form load

```
//I tried this but it is given me wrong path
textBox1.Text = Path.GetFullPath(@"Images12345");
//then slideshow
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(textBox1.Text+"/"+pics[0]);
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Interval = 5000;
i = 0;
```

Comment: what are you trying to get?  what isn't working?

Comment: Do you want the full path of the folder? Such as `C:\Pictures\Images12345`?

Comment: I want the full path of the folder "Images123455" Yes @puretppc like that.

Comment: what "wrong path" is it giving you?

Comment: it is giving me this path C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\PJ\PJ-Projects\H2ABoo\H2ABoo\bin\Debug\Images12345..  It must be C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\PJ\PJ-Projects\H2ABoo\H2ABoo\Images12345 i don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use this to get the application folder plus your images folder:

```
string applicationPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images12345");
```

Second, always use `Path.Combine` to work with paths:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(myFolderPath, pics[0]));
```

---

**NOTE**

You'll need to copy images folder where the executable is. That's your `bin/Degub` while you're debugging. You can navigate two folders up, but you must to implement this **like you were in production**, when the executable will be right next to your image folder.

---

**EDIT**

Maybe it's a better approach to use the current user's pictures folder. Like this:

```
string userPicturesFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
string imagesFolder = Path.Combine(userPicturesFolderPath, "Images12345");
```

Comment: @DontStopLearning You welcome! Check out my edit, maybe it will get things easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

You already found `Path.GetFullPath`... you should also look at `Path.Combine` to make a path out of multiple pieces, instead of just using string concatenation.